# how to configure kayenta-canary deployment to several k8s clusters

Tags: spinnaker, canary-deployment

Env details:

1. several k8s clusters: deployed through binary packages,
2. cloud provider: kubernetes provider v2 ?
3. kayenta pod: running

ERROR details:

- can't save canary config: Error 400  post http://gate/v2/canaryConfig
- only gce and aws resource type are available, but I don't have either cloud provider of them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhVWa.png)

This is my canary config:

```
  canary:
    enabled: true
    serviceIntegrations:
    - name: google
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      gcsEnabled: false
      stackdriverEnabled: false
    - name: prometheus
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-prometheus
        endpoint:
          baseUrl: <http://prometheus-svc.namespace:port>
        supportedTypes:
        - METRICS_STORE
    - name: datadog
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    - name: signalfx
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    - name: aws
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-minio
        bucket: spin-b81fd9b0-5ca9-456f-895a-efbd31612f80
        rootFolder: kayenta
        endpoint: <http://my-minio-svc.namespace:9000>
        accessKeyId: <miniokey>
        secretAccessKey: <miniosecret>
        supportedTypes:
        - CONFIGURATION_STORE
        - OBJECT_STORE
      s3Enabled: true
    - name: newrelic
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    reduxLoggerEnabled: true
    defaultMetricsAccount: my-prometheus-account
    defaultStorageAccount: my-minio
    defaultJudge: NetflixACAJudge-v1.0
    defaultMetricsStore: prometheus
    stagesEnabled: true
    templatesEnabled: true
    showAllConfigsEnabled: true
```

Canary stage failed details: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5639

Comment: Please add more details and context (such as code examples) at your question

Comment: Thank you!  I added my canary config just now

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the following error The was an error saving your config: 400 when you are trying to save your “Canary Config”, add the following setting:

Halyard

In .hal/default/profiles/gate-local.yml, add the following snippet:

```
services:
  kayenta:
    canaryConfigStore: true
```

Operator

In your SpinnakerService manifest, add the following snippet:

```
apiVersion: spinnaker.armory.io/v1alpha2
  kind: SpinnakerService
  metadata:
    name: spinnaker
  spec:
    spinnakerConfig:
      profiles:
        gate:
          services:
            kayenta:
              canaryConfigStore: true
```

Resource: https://docs.armory.io/docs/spinnaker-user-guides/canary/kayenta-canary-use/